# Implicit parameter not passed to higher-order function

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, implicit

I have a function which wraps the call to Anorm's SQL function in a Future:

```
def sqlWithFuture[T](sql: => T) = Future(DB.withConnection(con => sql))
```

Using it in a Model:

```
def userQuery = sqlWithFuture(SQL("select init()").as(...))
```

yields:

"could not find implicit value for parameter connection: java.sql.Connection"

Any way to pull the implicit connection parameter(con) back into scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are working with Play 2.0.

Let's look at DB http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0/scala/play/api/db/DB$.html

```
def
withConnection [A] (block: (Connection) ⇒ A)(implicit app: Application): A
```

Execute a block of code, providing a JDBC connection. The connection and all created statements are automatically released.

The SQL object let you create an anorm.SqlQuery : http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#anorm.SqlQuery

```
def as [T] (parser: ResultSetParser[T])(implicit connection: Connection): T
```

So the problem here is with your signature:

```
def sqlWithFuture[T](sql: => T) = Future(DB.withConnection(con => sql))
```

Nothing says that the connection should be passed to the sql block.

```
def sqlWithFuture[T](sql: Connection => T) = Future(DB.withConnection(con => sql(con))
```